# What does :&lt;i&gt; code stand for in subtitles?

Tags: text-processing

I downloaded a subtitle from subscene http://subscene.com/subtitles/the-5th-wave/english/1298314 and it contains some coding such as `:&lt;i&gt;` and `&lt;/i&gt;` which is not being decoded by my player mpv . As can be seen the subtitle is in .srt (Subrip Text) format.

https://matroska.org/technical/specs/subtitles/srt.html

Here's a full dialog so that it may make sense.

```
28
00:03:37,080 --> 00:03:39,280
CASSIE:&lt;i&gt; I miss the Cassie I was.&lt;/i&gt;
```

I want to fix this so that the codes are not visible during play but don't know how. Can somebody help. I am on Debian testing and using mpv

```
[$] mpv --version                                                                                                               
(null) requires an argument
mpv 0.14.0 (C) 2000-2015 mpv/MPlayer/mplayer2 projects
 built on UNKNOWN
ffmpeg library versions:
   libavutil       54.31.100
   libavcodec      56.60.100
   libavformat     56.40.101
   libswscale      3.1.101
   libavfilter     5.40.101
   libswresample   1.2.101
ffmpeg version: 2.8.6-1+b2
```

Look forward to how this can be fixed. Those codes are throughout the whole .srt file so its a bit disconcerting at best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like someone tried to use HTML tags for the subtitles and tried to make the fonts *italic*. In my limited HTML knowledge, `&lt;` stands for `less than` sign, i.e. `<` and `&gt;` stands for `>`. So

```
CASSIE:&lt;i&gt; I miss the Cassie I was.&lt;/i&gt;
```

can be visualized as

```
CASSIE:<i> I miss the Cassie I was.</i>
```

as you can easily see this is Italic code and the video player doesn't understand html tags. I am pretty sure they can be removed by few select sed/awk combinations, something like

```
sed 's/\&lt\;i\&gt\;//; s+\&lt\;/i\&gt\;++' somefile.srt >somefile-nohtml.srt
```

Comment: It seems like someone tried to use html codes and failed spectacularlly. In particular in HTML you use the entities for less than and greater than when you DON'T want them to be interpreted as html markup.

Comment: could you share how I could do that ? Actually just doing the latter instead of the HTML tags did the trick. I just changed that one line manually, but changing throughout the document would be better/nicer. I did mark your answer as the answer :)

Comment: `sed 's/\&lt\;i\&gt\;//' srtfilename |sed 's+\&lt\;/i\&gt\;++'`